# Debian10 Touchpad in basic mode after halt

Tags: debian, touchpad, synaptic, halt

I run Debian 10/Gnome on a Lenovo Y2P, so far without problem. In particular `uname -a` yields:

```
Linux deepthought 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Since I once ran `sudo halt` on 4.19.0-11-amd64, `synclient -l` yields:

> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

I.e. the touchpad works, but less sensitive, no 2-FingerScroll, no click-drag, and the Mouse & Touchpad settings menu is reduced to a basic form. On the previous version, 4.19.0-10-amd64 the touchpad still works completely normal.

Here is, what I tried so far:

1. I have `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` installed (and re-installed, to no avail).
2. As in this [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210144/synclient-does-not-find-synaptics-properties-despite-synaptics-touchpad-in-xinpu) answer, `xinput list` yields:

> ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]

but copying the synaptics config file, as suggested:

```
cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
```

and rebooting did not solve the problem. The content of `70-synaptics.conf` is:

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
#       MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

3. [Re-adding](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-after-reboot-no-synaptics-driver-loaded/) the module to the kernel did not help but tells me this:
   `insmod /lib/modules/4.19.0-13-amd64/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko proto=imps`
4. Following [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/4lilcs/no_synaptics_driver_loaded_after_upgrade/) reddit, i checked `dmesg` like so:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i PS/2
[    1.799257] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    1.812958] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.218457] input: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[  246.027504] input: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input81
```

However, my xorg log contains nothing about Synaptics:

```
[   189.259] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   189.259] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[   189.259] Current Operating System: Linux deepthought 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64
[   189.259] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-10-amd64 root=UUID=48c75b27-4eb3-426f-9a8b-80bac1fc66d5 ro quiet
[   189.259] Build Date: 05 March 2019  08:11:12PM
[   189.259] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[   189.259] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[   189.259]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   189.259] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   189.260] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug  6 14:41:07 2020
[   189.260] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   189.260] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   189.261] Parse error on line 3 of section Device in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf
        "MatchDriver" is not a valid keyword in this section.
[   189.262] (EE) Problem parsing the config file
[   189.262] (EE) Error parsing the config file
[   189.262] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   189.262] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   189.262] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   189.262] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   189.262] (EE) 
[   189.262] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The error in here stems from another halted project - it has not influenced the synaptics driver in the past. But I don't see anything about the latter.

(side question: i removed the file `20-displaylink.conf` a while ago, i.e. this file doesn't exist anymore. when/how does this log get updated?)

5. As I expected, adding the module automatically at start up, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579293/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-after-reboot-no-synaptics-driver-loaded) did not change anything.
6. This [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211112) tells me, that Gnome 3.20 no longer supports synaptic drivers, but switched to libinput. I have 3.30.2., so while the behavior would make sense, I have the same Gnome version on the Kernel version 4.19.0-10-amd64, and it works just fine.
   Anyhow, this wiki entry should then tell me how to switch to libinput - but i seem to be too stupehd for that, i.e. I don't get what I need to do.

Now, slowly desperation kicks in, as I am not (yet) familiar enough with Linux, to cook up my own solution. Hence, any help is greatly appreciated.
Also: how could `halt` mess this up? Is there some danger to it, I should know about?

Thank you big time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone encountering the same problem in the future:
I resolved this issue by reinstalling the OS. Sorry I don't have better news.